# joining 2 tables to find closest timestamps

Tags: mysql

So I have 1 MySQL table  with sales and the price and time at which it was sold. I have a second table with the average price for each item in the marketplace captured every 5 minutes. These things can change price minute to minute.

I need to get the market price from table 2 for each item sold that's closest to the sale time both before and after the sale.

I've been trying to split it up into getting price prior and the price after the sale as 2 separate queries. What I've got so far is below. The problem with it though is it only orders the market.time after the rows have been set. I need it to order by the market.time before the GROUP BY statement picks the top row per sales.id (hopefully that made sense). Basically it returns the earliest price listed for the item that got sold, and then the whole table is ordered by those times.

```
SELECT sales.id, sales.price, sales.time, sales.item_id, market.time, market.price,
FROM sales_table sales
INNER JOIN market_table market ON market.item_id = sales.item_id
WHERE market.time < sales.time
GROUP BY sales.id
ORDER BY market.time DESC;
```

sales table

```
| id | price|         time                   | item_id  |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     0.5  | 2006-10-05 11:55:44        | 5        |
|  2 |     1.1  | 2007-10-07 12:34:17        | 5        | 
|  3 |     0.4  | 2008-10-09 08:19:36        | 9        |
|  4 |     5.8  | 2010-10-13 04:28:14        | 1        |
```

market table

```
| id | price|         time                   | item_id  |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     0.5  | 2006-10-05 11:50:00        | 1        |
|  2 |     1.1  | 2006-10-05 11:55:00        | 1        |
|  3 |     0.4  | 2008-10-09 02:20:00        | 2        |
|  4 |     5.8  | 2010-10-09 04:25:00        | 2        |
```

desired result

```
| s_id | s_price|      sales_time     | item_id| market_time        |m_price
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   0.5  | 2006-10-05 11:55:44 | 5      | 2006-10-05 11:55:00| 0.5
|  2   |   1.1  | 2007-10-07 12:34:17 | 5      | 2007-10-07 12:30:00| 1.2
|  3   |   0.4  | 2008-10-09 08:19:36 | 9      | 2008-10-09 08:15:00| 0.45
|  4   |   5.8  | 2010-10-13 04:28:14 | 1      | 2010-10-13 04:25:00| 6.0
```

what I'm currently getting from my above query

```
| s_id | s_price|      sales_time     | item_id| market_time        |m_price
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   0.5  | 2006-10-05 11:55:44 | 5      | 2001-01-01 00:00:00| 1.0
|  2   |   1.1  | 2007-10-07 12:34:17 | 5      | 2002-06-01 09:15:00| 0.8
|  3   |   0.4  | 2008-10-09 08:19:36 | 9      | 2002-08-14 15:30:00| 0.2
|  4   |   5.8  | 2010-10-13 04:28:14 | 1      | 2003-10-01 12:00:00| 5.2
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Ouch...I'm glad it's not my question ;-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm still labouring under the vain hope that if I say it often enough, the message may eventually get through to somebody.

Comment: I've never written a question to stack overflow before. I'm not fully aware of all the protocols on how to avoid asking something terrible.

Comment: @Strawberry, I've added some examples for the tables. I think that's what you were suggesting I do to improve it.

Comment: Hi @mehigasf, and welcome to SO. Nope. That's not what I was suggesting. What I was suggesting is precisely spelled out in 3 bullet points in the answer to the linked 'meta' question.

Comment: i dont think you want the market price closest to the sale time, surely only the last recorded market price can be considered valid

Comment: @pancho018,  I want the last recorded price prior to the sale, and the first recorded price after the sale. I figured splitting it up into 2 queries would be simpler.

Comment: @mehigasf thats how i would have done it. i'd look at the link provided by Strawberry and look at building an SQLFIDDLE and some decent sample data that works so people can have a go and be more helpful.

Comment: I've now solved my problem a totally different (and slightly cheating) way. I did an inner join of the 2 tables and put that into a new table. Then the data was easier to manipulate by getting min(sale_time - price_time) as time_diff where time_diff >0

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer below, it might help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Please use by Row Number .

```
select id, time, price, time, price from (
    SELECT sales.id, sales.time, sales.price, market.time, market.price, row_number() over (partition by sales.id order by ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, market.time, sales.time))) as r
    FROM sales_table sales
    INNER JOIN market_table market ON market.item_id = sales.item_id
) as t
where t.r = 1
ORDER BY market.time DESC;
```

Comment: The question seems to be about MySQL

Comment: it is, I was wondering why I was getting errors around the row_number part.